# Tools to create a binding wrapper for a c++ class

Tags: qt, wrapper

i have a C++ library written with Qt that i want to use with different languages: pure C++, java, C, c#, etc.

So far i have created a perl script that scans the main header files of the library and creates the relative wrapper classes to be used by other languages. Unfortunately this was my first attempt at this and the script has now become too unreadable and (for me) unmaintainable (i am, by no means, a perl expert).

So i wanted to restart from scratch, what would be the best tools to accomplish this? another (better thought) script? python (for readability over perl) or are there any good frameworks to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You may look at this tool https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/intro
This is realy powerfull tool and this project has good documentation.

Comment: Hi Andrey, sip seems to be a great tool but it is just to generate python bindings but I want to generate multiple languages.

Comment: @Alienpenguin i think you would not find universal wrapper tool for all languages(even for base). It's should be massive project with plugins i suppose. And i've never saw something like that. I wrote about sip because it could be a base for your project.